# "TypeError: document is undefined" with jquery-1.10.2.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, backbone.js

I am creating a BackboneJS project. It works fine in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox I get errors that stop my app from loading and I cannot work out why.

The error is in my jQuery file but it is obviously something in my app that is triggering it because the jQuery library is fine on its own.

It is throwing an error on the second line of the jQuery "createSafeFragment" method:

```
function createSafeFragment( document ) {
    var list = nodeNames.split( "|" ),
        safeFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    if ( safeFrag.createElement ) {
        while ( list.length ) {
            safeFrag.createElement(
                list.pop()
            );
        }
    }
    return safeFrag;
}
```

My main.js that runs the app:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
    if (this.beforeClose) {
        this.beforeClose();
    }
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
};

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '': 'home',
        'login' : 'login',
        'register' : 'register',
        'rosters' : 'rosters',
        'workplaces' : 'workplaces',
        'groups' : 'groups',
        'shifts' : 'shifts',
        'logout' : 'logout'
    },

    content : '#content',

    initialize: function () {
        window.headerView = new HeaderView();
        $('.header').html(window.headerView.render().el);
    },

    home: function () {
        window.homePage = window.homePage ? window.homePage : new HomePageView();
        app.showView( content, window.homePage);
        window.headerView.select('home');
    },

    register: function () {
        window.registerPage = window.registerPage ? window.registerPage : new RegisterPageView();
        app.showView( content, window.registerPage);
        window.headerView.select('register');
    },

    login: function() {
        app.showView( content, new LoginPageView());
        window.headerView.select('login');
    },

    rosters: function () {
        if(Utils.checkLoggedIn()){
            app.showView( content, new RosterPageView());
            window.headerView.select('rosters');
        }
    },

    groups: function () {
        if(Utils.checkLoggedIn()){
            app.showView( content, new GroupsPageView());
            window.headerView.select('groups');
        }
    },

    shifts: function () {
        if(Utils.checkLoggedIn()){
            app.showView( content, new ShiftsPageView());
            window.headerView.select('shifts');
        }
    },

    workplaces: function () {
        if(Utils.checkLoggedIn()){
            app.showView( content, new WorkplacesPageView());
            window.headerView.select('workplaces');
        }
    },

    logout: function () {
        window.headerView.toggleLogin(false);
        this.login();
    },

    showView: function(selector, view) {
        if (this.currentView)
            this.currentView.close();
        $(selector).html(view.render().el);
        this.currentView = view;
        return view;
    }

});

Utils.loadTemplates(['HomePageView', 'HeaderView', 'LoginPageView', 'RegisterPageView', 
                     'RostersPageView', 'GroupsPageView', 'ShiftsPageView', 'UserListView', 
                     'GroupListView', 'ShiftListView', 'SearchedUserListView', 'SearchedGroupListView', 
                     'GroupRosterView', 'RosterListView', 'WorkplacesPageView', 'WorkplaceListView',
                     'SearchedWorkplaceListView', 'RosterJoinListView', 'GroupUserListView',
                     'WorkplaceRosterView', 'WorkplaceUserListView', 'RosterShiftView'], function(){
    app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

And my Util.js:

```
Utils = {

    //template stuff
    templates: {},
    loadTemplates: function(names, callback) {

        var that = this;

        var loadTemplate = function(index) {
            var name = names[index];
            $.get('tpl/' + name + '.html', function(data) {
                that.templates[name] = data;
                index++;
                if (index < names.length) {
                    loadTemplate(index);
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        };

        loadTemplate(0);
    },

    get: function(name) {
        return this.templates[name];
    },

    //error stuff

    showAlertMessage: function(message, type){
        $('#error').html(message);
        $('.alert').addClass(type);
        $('.alert').show();
    },

    showErrors: function(errors) {
        _.each(errors, function (error) {
            var controlGroup = $('.' + error.name);
            controlGroup.addClass('error');
            controlGroup.find('.help-inline').text(error.message);
        }, this);
    },

    hideErrors: function () {
        $('.control-group').removeClass('error');
        $('.help-inline').text('');
    },

    //validator stuff

    validateModel: function(model, attrs){

        Utils.hideErrors();
        var valError = model.validate(attrs);
        if(valError){
            Utils.showErrors(valError);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },

    //loading stuff

    toggleLoading: function(toggle){
        $('#loading').css('visibility', toggle ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    },

    //login stuff

    login: function(auth){

        window.headerView.toggleLogin(true);
        Backbone.history.navigate("", true);
    },

    checkLoggedIn: function(){

        if(!window.userId){
            window.headerView.toggleLogin(false);
            Backbone.history.navigate("login", true);

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },

    //util methods

    formatDate: function(date){
        var formattedDate = '';
        formattedDate += date.getFullYear() + '-';
        formattedDate += date.getMonth()+1 + '-';
        formattedDate += date.getDate();
        return formattedDate;
    },

    formatDateForDisplay: function(date){
        var formattedDate = '';
        formattedDate += date.getDate() + '/';
        formattedDate += date.getMonth()+1 + '/';
        formattedDate += date.getFullYear() + ' - ';
        formattedDate += ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'][date.getDay()];
        return formattedDate;
    },

    formatDateForGroup: function(date){
        var formattedDate = '';
        formattedDate += date.getDate() + '/';
        formattedDate += date.getMonth()+1;
        return formattedDate;
    },

    showPopup: function(id, buttons, title, content){
        var popup = $(id);
        popup.dialog({
              modal: true,
              title: title,
              buttons: buttons
            }); 
        popup.find('#popupContent').html(content);
    }
};
```

Someone please help me as this is driving me crazy! Firefox only...

Answer (score 2):

I was also experiencing this problem. You can reproduce this error by doing:

```
$(window).append('bla');
```

Mine was cause by a combination of this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="doIt(); return false;">click</a>
```

and

```
function doIt(){
   var newElm = $('<span>hi</span>');
   $(this).append(newElm);
   //now this === window, and not what I was expecting the a-element
}
```

This all happened because I expected the click would have been binded in a <strike>proper</strike> more-jquery-ish way to the a element. But someone decided to use 1999 code ;p. I expected for the method to be bound like this:

```
$("a").click(doIt);
```

In which case *this* would have been bound to the a-element and not to the window.

Comment: I'm not sure how it was expected though, "this" is the a, in the onclick, which makes perfect sense.  When you call doIt(), the function is on the window object, so window becomes "this" when you call it.  You could do something like doIt.call(this); to force this to be the a.  When you bind to the a via addEventListener, this is the a, and if you were to call do it from within that function, this would be window again.  "this" does not follow function calls. Calling doIt like you are is exactly like saying "window.doIt()"

Comment: You must have misread my post. What you are describing is exactly the problem. This is a reference to window which causes the TypeError. The code given by me is a problem description explaning why it doesn' work as expected...

Comment: Yes, I know, but you posted that you expected it to bound in a proper way.  This was implying that it wasn't, but it actually was bound correctly.  Your example shows you calling a function outside of the click handler. I'm not sure how you expected 'this' to be an anchor element.

Answer (score 1):

benhowdle89 figured out that I was appending to `content` when I should have been appending to `this.content`.

It is also a good idea to always use JSFiddle I have realised, so other people can see your problem on their own.

Thanks to benhowdle89!